# Resolving shift/reduce conflicts with PLY

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, ply

I have the following grammar for the [setlx language](http://randoom.org/Software/SetlX) in PLY:

```
Rule 0     S' -> file_input
Rule 1     file_input -> statement_list
Rule 2     epsilon -> <empty>
Rule 3     statement_list -> statement
Rule 4     statement_list -> statement_list statement
Rule 5     statement -> simple_statement SEMICOLON
Rule 6     statement -> compound_statement
Rule 7     simple_statement -> expression_statement
Rule 8     simple_statement -> assert_statement
Rule 9     simple_statement -> assignment_statement
Rule 10    simple_statement -> augmented_assign_statement
Rule 11    simple_statement -> backtrack_statement
Rule 12    simple_statement -> break_statement
Rule 13    simple_statement -> continue_statement
Rule 14    simple_statement -> exit_statement
Rule 15    simple_statement -> return_statement
Rule 16    simple_statement -> quantor
Rule 17    simple_statement -> term
Rule 18    expression_statement -> expression
Rule 19    backtrack_statement -> BACKTRACK
Rule 20    break_statement -> BREAK
Rule 21    continue_statement -> CONTINUE
Rule 22    exit_statement -> EXIT
Rule 23    return_statement -> RETURN
Rule 24    return_statement -> RETURN expression
Rule 25    expression_list -> expression
Rule 26    expression_list -> expression_list COMMA expression
Rule 27    expression -> implication
Rule 28    expression -> lambda_definition
Rule 29    expression -> implication EQUIVALENT implication
Rule 30    expression -> implication ANTIVALENT implication
Rule 31    implication -> disjunction
Rule 32    implication -> disjunction IMPLICATES disjunction
Rule 33    disjunction -> conjunction
Rule 34    disjunction -> disjunction OR conjunction
Rule 35    conjunction -> comparison
Rule 36    conjunction -> conjunction AND comparison
Rule 37    comparison -> sum
Rule 38    comparison -> sum EQ sum
Rule 39    comparison -> sum NEQ sum
Rule 40    comparison -> sum LT sum
Rule 41    comparison -> sum LE sum
Rule 42    comparison -> sum GT sum
Rule 43    comparison -> sum GE sum
Rule 44    comparison -> sum IN sum
Rule 45    comparison -> sum NOTIN sum
Rule 46    sum -> product
Rule 47    sum -> sum PLUS product
Rule 48    sum -> sum MINUS product
Rule 49    product -> reduce
Rule 50    product -> product TIMES reduce
Rule 51    product -> product DIVIDE reduce
Rule 52    product -> product IDIVIDE reduce
Rule 53    product -> product MOD reduce
Rule 54    product -> product CARTESIAN reduce
Rule 55    reduce -> unary_expression
Rule 56    reduce -> reduce SUM unary_expression
Rule 57    reduce -> reduce PRODUCT unary_expression
Rule 58    unary_expression -> power
Rule 59    unary_expression -> SUM unary_expression
Rule 60    unary_expression -> PRODUCT unary_expression
Rule 61    unary_expression -> HASH unary_expression
Rule 62    unary_expression -> MINUS unary_expression
Rule 63    unary_expression -> AT unary_expression
Rule 64    unary_expression -> BANG unary_expression
Rule 65    power -> primary
Rule 66    power -> primary POW unary_expression
Rule 67    primary -> atom
Rule 68    primary -> attributeref
Rule 69    primary -> subscription
Rule 70    primary -> slicing
Rule 71    primary -> procedure
Rule 72    primary -> call
Rule 73    primary -> primary BANG
Rule 74    atom -> identifier
Rule 75    atom -> literal
Rule 76    atom -> enclosure
Rule 77    identifier -> IDENTIFIER
Rule 78    identifier -> UNUSED
Rule 79    attributeref -> primary DOT identifier
Rule 80    subscription -> primary LBRACKET expression RBRACKET
Rule 81    slicing -> primary LBRACKET lower_bound RANGE upper_bound RBRACKET
Rule 82    lower_bound -> expression
Rule 83    lower_bound -> epsilon
Rule 84    upper_bound -> expression
Rule 85    upper_bound -> epsilon
Rule 86    literal -> stringliteral
Rule 87    literal -> integer
Rule 88    literal -> floatnumber
Rule 89    literal -> boolean
Rule 90    stringliteral -> STRING
Rule 91    stringliteral -> LITERAL
Rule 92    integer -> INTEGER
Rule 93    floatnumber -> DOUBLE
Rule 94    boolean -> TRUE
Rule 95    boolean -> FALSE
Rule 96    enclosure -> parenth_form
Rule 97    enclosure -> set_display
Rule 98    enclosure -> list_display
Rule 99    parenth_form -> LPAREN expression RPAREN
Rule 100   set_display -> LBRACE expression RANGE expression RBRACE
Rule 101   set_display -> LBRACE expression COMMA expression RANGE expression RBRACE
Rule 102   set_display -> LPAREN argument_list RPAREN
Rule 103   list_display -> LBRACKET expression RANGE expression RBRACKET
Rule 104   list_display -> LBRACKET expression COMMA expression RANGE expression RBRACKET
Rule 105   list_display -> LBRACKET argument_list RBRACKET
Rule 106   lambda_definition -> lambda_parameters LAMBDADEF expression
Rule 107   lambda_parameters -> identifier
Rule 108   lambda_parameters -> LT parameter_list GT
Rule 109   assignment_statement -> target ASSIGN expression
Rule 110   target -> expression
Rule 111   augmented_assign_statement -> augtarget augop expression
Rule 112   augtarget -> identifier
Rule 113   augtarget -> attributeref
Rule 114   augtarget -> subscription
Rule 115   augop -> PLUS_EQUAL
Rule 116   augop -> MINUS_EQUAL
Rule 117   augop -> TIMES_EQUAL
Rule 118   augop -> DIVIDE_EQUAL
Rule 119   augop -> IDIVIDE_EQUAL
Rule 120   augop -> MOD_EQUAL
Rule 121   assert_statement -> ASSERT LPAREN expression COMMA expression RPAREN
Rule 122   term -> TERM LPAREN term_arguments RPAREN
Rule 123   term_arguments -> expression_list
Rule 124   term_arguments -> epsilon
Rule 125   procedure -> PROCEDURE LPAREN parameter_list RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE
Rule 126   procedure -> CPROCEDURE LPAREN parameter_list RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE
Rule 127   parameter_list -> procedure_param
Rule 128   parameter_list -> parameter_list COMMA procedure_param
Rule 129   parameter_list -> epsilon
Rule 130   procedure_param -> identifier
Rule 131   call -> primary LPAREN argument_list RPAREN
Rule 132   call -> primary LPAREN RPAREN
Rule 133   argument_list -> expression
Rule 134   argument_list -> argument_list COMMA expression
Rule 135   quantor -> FORALL LPAREN iterator_chain PIPE expression RPAREN
Rule 136   quantor -> EXISTS LPAREN iterator_chain PIPE expression RPAREN
Rule 137   iterator -> target IN expression
Rule 138   iterator_chain -> iterator
Rule 139   iterator_chain -> iterator_chain COMMA iterator
Rule 140   compound_statement -> if_statement
Rule 141   compound_statement -> switch_statement
Rule 142   compound_statement -> match_statement
Rule 143   compound_statement -> while_loop
Rule 144   compound_statement -> do_while_loop
Rule 145   compound_statement -> for_loop
Rule 146   block -> statement_list
Rule 147   block -> epsilon
Rule 148   if_statement -> IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE
Rule 149   if_statement -> IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE ELSE LBRACE block RBRACE
Rule 150   if_statement -> IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE ELSE if_statement
Rule 151   switch_statement -> SWITCH LBRACE case_statements default_case RBRACE
Rule 152   case_statements -> case_list
Rule 153   case_statements -> epsilon
Rule 154   case_list -> case_statement
Rule 155   case_list -> case_list case_statement
Rule 156   case_statement -> CASE expression COLON block
Rule 157   default_case -> DEFAULT COLON block
Rule 158   default_case -> epsilon
Rule 159   match_statement -> MATCH
Rule 160   while_loop -> WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE
Rule 161   do_while_loop -> DO LBRACE block RBRACE WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN SEMICOLON
Rule 162   for_loop -> FOR LPAREN iterator_chain RPAREN LBRACE block RBRACE
```

On the last few meters, I now get some conflicts:

```
WARNING: 
WARNING: Conflicts:
WARNING: 
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for IN in state 34 resolved as shift
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for COMMA in state 94 resolved as shift
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for RPAREN in state 154 resolved as shift
```

How can I resolve them without generating new conflicts? I understand where they come from, but I have no idea about fixing it. Any help or general advice is appriciated.

Comment: By the way, it's nice that you know where the conflicts come from, but it would have been nicer if you'd included that information rather than forcing a responder to work through 162 productions to figure it out. :) (bison helped quite a bit, but still...) Also, you have three different non-terminals which produce a comma-separated list of expressions. You might be able to simplify a bit.

Comment: expression_list has minimum lenght of 1, whereas argument_list can be empty. I admit, I can express expression_list as expression + argument_list. Where is the third nonterminal producing a comma seperated list of expressions? I just found  procedure_params, but there are identifier, not expressions in there.

Comment: argument_list can't be empty but term_argument can. There's no real need for the epsilon production for term_argument, though; you could handle it the same way as you do a call. parameter_list is probably incorrect since it produces ,,,identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll do these backwards, because that way we go from easiest to hardest. In fact, I don't really have a solution for the first conflict.

The third conflict is the result of an actual ambiguity in the grammar. You need to get rid of the ambiguity:

```
Rule 96    enclosure -> parenth_form
Rule 97    enclosure -> set_display
Rule 99    parenth_form -> LPAREN expression RPAREN
Rule 102   set_display -> LPAREN argument_list RPAREN
Rule 133   argument_list -> expression
```

Consequently, if we're looking for an `enclosure` and we find a simple parenthesized expression, it could either be a `parenth_form` or it could be a `set_display` containing an `argument_list` of exactly one expression. I suspect that the intention here is that a simple parenthesized expression would be a `parenth_form`, but there's no way to tell from the grammar.

The simplest solution would be to just get rid of `parenth_form` altogether, and check for the case of a one-element `argument_list` when you build the AST node for a `set_display` corresponding to rule 102. Another possibility is to be explicit about it; change Rule 102 to require the `set_display` to have at least two expressions:

```
set_display -> LPAREN expression COMMA argument_list RPAREN
```

That still requires you to juggle the AST, though, because you have to prepend the `expression` to the `argument_list` when you build the `set_display` node.

The second S/R conflict is actually quite similar. It arises because of:

```
Rule 104   list_display -> LBRACKET expression COMMA expression RANGE expression RBRACKET
Rule 105   list_display -> LBRACKET argument_list RBRACKET
```

So:

```
LBRACKET expression COMMA expression ...
```

would require reduction by Rule 104 if the following symbol is `RANGE`; by Rule 105 if the following symbol is `RBRACKET`; and by Rule 134 if the following symbol is `COMMA`. (That's a rough approximation, since it assumes that we already know the end of the second `expression`.) As written, though, the grammar needs to commit to one of these paths as soon as it sees the first `COMMA`, because it needs to decide at that moment whether to create an `argument_list` or not.

The solution is to delay the parser's decision, which is easy but ugly:

```
list_display -> LBRACKET expression RANGE expression RBRACKET
list_display -> LBRACKET expression COMMA expression RANGE expression RBRACKET
list_display -> LBRACKET expression RBRACKET
list_display -> LBRACKET expression COMMA argument_list RBRACKET
```

Now, the first `COMMA` is always shifted and the decision on what type of `list_display` to reduce is delayed until the end of the second `expression` (if there are two `expression`s), but it's necessary to juggle the AST for the last two productions to correct the `argument_list`.

The first S/R conflict arises because `IN` is used both as an operator and as a syntactic part of an `iterator`:

```
Rule 44    comparison -> sum IN sum
Rule 137   iterator -> target IN expression
```

But because `target` is just an `expression`, and `expression` can derive `sum`, it's not possible (most of the time) for the parser to know which `IN` it's looking at until much later in the parse.

The previous technique of deferring the decision won't work here, because you need to know which type of `IN` you're looking at in order to correctly apply operator precedence. Suppose we're in a context where we need an `iterator` and the input is:

```
atom1 AND atom2 IN atom3
```

If that's the iterator (i.e., the next symbol is `COMMA` or `RPAREN`), then that is, effectively:

```
( atom1 AND atom2 ) IN atom3
```

However, if that's the left-hand side of an iterator, then it needs to be parsed completely differently:

```
( atom1 AND ( atom2 IN atom3 ) ) IN expression
```

Moreover, `atom3` could have been an arbitrary expression, perhaps `atom3 AND atom4`, leading to the two parses:

```
( atom1 AND atom2 ) IN ( atom3 AND atom4 )
( atom1 AND ( atom2 IN atom3 ) AND atom4 ) IN expression
```

This is why puns are bad in language design.

I strongly suspect that there is no `LR(k)` grammar which will be able to parse that particular corner of your language, although that's just based on intuition; I have no proof. However, a GLR parser would have no trouble with it, because it is not actually ambiguous. I don't know if there is a GLR parser generator in Python; if you're not tied to Python, you could certainly use `bison`.

The GLR parser would also have solved the second conflict, which is also not the result of an ambiguity.